# git format-patch with several ranges

Tags: git

How can I generate a single numbered list of patches from several separate ranges?

Let's say I need patches from *range A* and *range B* in the git tree.
For the sake of simplicity, let's say each range has 10 patches.

The usual way to generate those patches would be two separate git commands:

```
git format-patch range_A_from..range_A_to
git format-patch range_B_from..range_B_to
```

The result of this would be **two separate lists of patches**, each numbered from 0001 to 0010.
What I want is a single list of patches numbered from **0001** to **0020**, so that it would be clear who comes first.

Any way doing this with git w/o the need to rename the patch files?

Comment: See the `--start-number` option. Alternatively, you can generate them all to stdout instead of putting them in separate files.

Comment: You can create a temporary branch containing exactly the required commits. `git rebase --interactive` is a good UI for that. Bonus: You will see conflicts which are caused by the "missing" commits.

Comment: @torek that could work :)
 Please post as an answer.

Comment: It's annoying to use because format-patch doesn't tell you how many it made. (It also, as @A.H. noted, runs the risk of producing patches that won't apply.)

Comment: Sure, but I'm not interested in resolving patch conflicts here.  I just want to have a list of the patches. 
Interactive rebase is no good here as well - it requires me actually fix all the conflicts and apply the patches on the current branch.
What I'm looking for is preparing the list of patches and applying them on a different tree/branch/whatever (and there I will need to resolve the conflicts).

Comment: Strange... If you do NOT intend to send the patches (via email or so) to another repo then `format-patch`  is the wrong tool. Transporting patches WITHIN one repo is the prime jobs of `rebase --interactive` and/or `cherry-pick`.

Comment: I didn't say that... In fact I did say that I want to create the patches and then apply them on different tree. Not sure how you came to this conclusion.
I any case, format-patch is the right tool for this.

Comment: Well you used the term "tree" not "repository".

Comment: OK, I see your point .
In that case, the "tree" can be in another "repository" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by @torek in the comment: see the `--start-number` option.